# Snells Law question

Tags: optics, refraction

My nephew asked me to help him on his physics homework. I'm alright as physics, but it is by no means a strong point (it's been a looooooong time since I did any physics). He was presented with this diagram:

[image]

He had some simple enough questions such as "why does the light change direction" and "what happens when the light reaches the other side of the glass cube". I helped him and he was able to answer the homework questions he had been presented with.

**The assigned homework at this point had been completed. What follows is my own curiosity and nothing to do with the homework questions**

(why does the light change direction etc) but just because I was curious, I wanted to just work it out a little more because according to the internet, glass has a refractive index of $1.52$, and air almost $1$. Snells law ($n_1 sin(x_1) = n_2 sin(x_2))$ would then allow me to work out the refractive angle. So, using 1 for $n_1$, $1.52$ for $n_2$, and $60°$ for $x_1$, I calculated a refractive angle of $40.28°$. That is nowhere near the $55$ on the diagram. I looked online for a few examples in case I had doen somethign horribly wrong, but all the diagrams showed light entering the top of and exiting the bottom of a rectangle, like this one:

[image]

This shows the angles for point A are the same, but the angles from point B (in the original diagram) are not measured in the same place. According to the internet, to get that refractive angle, it would be $90°$ - the $55$ shown here. That would make it $35°$... still not the $40.28$ I calculated.

I decided to use [snells law calculator](https://www.omnicalculator.com/physics/snells-law), and used 1 as the refractive index 1, and $60$ for angle of incidence. When using 55 as angle of refraction, I get $1.057$ as the refractive index of the glass medium..... If I use 35, the refractive index becomes $1.51$.

From what I can see, I cannot find those values as a refractive index for glass.

So, am I being an idiot and I have done something wrong, or was my nephews tutor just sticking in any old number for fun? (I know I am overthinking this, but it was bugging me!)

Comment: It would help if you show us the details of the calculation that leads to 40.28 ${}^\circ$.  If you use the Snell's law calculator that you point to, you do not get 40.28 ${}^\circ$

Comment: @garyp Showing more calculations will not prevent this from being a "check my work" question.

Comment: @BioPhysicist do you guys not help with questions where people have attempted to do something, and want to find where they have gone wrong then?

Comment: [In general, no](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/179151). Conceptual questions are preferred over asking about specific calculations.

Comment: @BioPhysicist I agree, but I chose to bend the rule.  He's trying to help his nephew. He's not learning physics, doing homework, or addressing a question out of idle curiosity, for all of which finding the error would do no good. The intent of the rule is to prevent answers that do no good.  Helping him help his nephew does some good.

Comment: @garyp I am not trying to prevent doing good, but at the same time one could argue that about any question ultimately. However, here is not the place for such a discussion.

Comment: @BioPhysicist I'll keep that in mind for the future. Thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$55°$ is perfectly depicted in this diagram as:

$$n_1 \sin(\theta_i) = n_2 \sin(\theta_r) $$

$$ 1.0 \sin (60°) = 1.5 \sin(\theta_r) $$

$$ \sin(\theta_r) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} $$

$$ \theta_r = 35° $$

So the angle at $ B = 90° - 35° = 55° $
Hope that clears your doubt.

Comment: Welcome!  To make your equations more readable, please do what we all do here and use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/143293) for mathematics.

Comment: As you're a new poster note we have a homework-type question policy and *in general* we do not supply detailed answers to [homework-type questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714).  It's an important policy on Physics SE so please check it out.

Comment: Whoops. Just looked at my handwritten note. Turns out my handwriting is not even legible to myself and after writing numbers down I put them in the calculator wrong! Doh!

Comment: @StephenG I understand that, but for one thing, this isnt my homework. For another, I wasnt asking for a detailed answer. I showed my work and what I did, just wanted to know where I went wrong is all. This went through the exact same method I did, and allowed me to find what I did wrong. Also, if you read the question, I wasnt asking for the answer to homework. I had already done that, this was just something on top which I just wanted to do myself

Comment: @StephenG I have edited the question to try and make it a bit clearer

Comment: @StephenG makes a good point, but I did want to clarify that what the policy prohibits is answering the _actual assigned homework problem_ (or puzzle, self-study problem, etc.) which prompted the question. A good question for this site should ask about some specific conceptual difficulty encountered in the process of solving the problem, or inspired by the problem, and an answer which addresses only that specific conceptual difficulty but does not give away the answer to the underlying problem should be fine. While it's hard to tell for sure, I believe this answer falls in that category.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the confusion is that glass is a word describing thousands of materials. And second the refractive index is wavelength (color) dependent. There are many glasses with refractive index of 1.51 for visible colors.

If you calculated 1.51 (correctly calculated from 35°), then that is the refractive index and it is correct.

And the calculation assuming $\theta_1=60°$ angle of incidence and the refractive angle $\theta_2=40.3°$ for an $n=1.52$ is incorrect. Check your calculator, if its in radians or degrees.

Comment: Whoever decided that my answer, clearing the confusion OP has:

*From what I can see, I cannot find those values as a refractive index for glass.

So, am I being an idiot and I have done something wrong, or was my nephews tutor just sticking in any old number for fun?"*

was not helpful, should at least provide some context of why, or improve any answer here, which I do not see.
Secondly I do not know where OP got his answer wrong. I gave a suggestion of where to look and try again.